# Can I see the ip-address a remote server receives in my http-request

Tags: networking, ip-address

I use Windows 10 as developer and has to send a list of IP-addresses my host-provider has to "whitelist" (sorry the term). My http-requests get through some proxy-servers.

But can I in the response from the host (or in some other ways) see what IP-address they actually receives?

Maybe using the Postman tool or some other tricks.

Comment: This info should be obtained from the remote host if it is provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rocky foundation as it assumes the proxy servers (which appear to be out of your control) are not going to change.  Indeed I wonder if proxy servers are in use (which could break https) or if you are confusing cgn for proxy servers.

Anyway, the best way to get this is from the servers log file or, if you can run php or CGI put together a script with looks for REMOTE_ADDR attribute.

Untested but if you can run php something like the following:

```
  <?php
         echo "Remote IP: ". $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  ?>
```